# Remove POST data when using custom javascript back button

Tags: javascript, php, session, cookies, navigation

I've coded some custom navigation buttons into the project I'm working on, via javascript - they essentially copy the browser button functionality (brief wasn't initially clear on why separate buttons were required, but they asked for them):

```
function goBack() { window.history.back(); }
function goForward() { window.history.forward(); }
```

However, as the functionality is the same as the browser back button, the website asks if I want to resubmit POST data if I go back to a page with said POST data, which is undesirable.  Ideally, to fit with the current site setup (all POSTs submit to the originating page, which checks for POST data and performs the relevant submissions to the database), I want to clear the POST data so there is no request to resubmit.

I'm not familiar with the Post/Redirect/Get (PRG) that people might recommend, and it doesn't seem to cover the concept of continually pressing "back"; if you submit a form, you post to a page which handles the post action, then redirects to a GET page - but the redirect is still in the history, meaning if you go back, surely you would hit the redirect page and just be sent "forward"? Plus, PRG seems mostly centred on page refreshing, which is not what I'm looking for at the moment.

The concept of PRG also seems to be due to the browser back button not allowing for additional code to control POST data, so coders have to make the best of what they can access.

With my relative freedom of having a custom back button which could allow for manipulation of POST/session/cookie data, I'd consider there should be some method of calling a global session variable or cookie on back button press, which then gets picked up on the previous page load to unset the POST data and the global session variable/cookie, but my attempts to implement something like this have not succeeded - they've been simple single-line `setcookie('back', true)` or `set($_SESSION['back']=true)` PHP snippets within `goBack()`, with PHP earlier in the page:

```
<?php if (isset([either set cookie or set session variable]) {
    unset([either set cookie or set session variable]); // also tried changing 'true' to 'false' here
    unset($_POST);
}?>
```

Is this kind of behaviour possible and I'm just looking at this from the wrong angle, or is the only way to do a successful back action while suppressing POST to re-engineer the site to use PRG, which will be comparatively significant legwork? Is there some other point in a page load/POST submit that would allow for clearing the POST data, to allow for the back button functionality I'm looking for?

**EDIT**

I, as an example, navigate to `site.com/stuff/edit/[an ID]`, to edit an item of stuff. The first time I visit, there is no POST data, so the PHP check of isset($_POST) returns false and the page is simply rendered with a form which is populated by a GET.

I amend in the form and press submit. The submit sends the POST data to the target page; this is STILL `site.com/stuff/edit/[an ID]`! However, because there is now POST data, the PHP picks this up, validates it on the page (you'll see why later) and performs backend model and controller functions to update the item to the database serving the site.

Depending on whether the update was successful, the page then renders the form again, with the information which is retrieved from a GET, which pulls the information from the server (amended or otherwise) and either a success or fail message.

If I want to add a new item, I navigate to `site.com/stuff/new`; this navigates to the same page as `site.com/stuff/edit`, but PHP code determines the masking URL and renders different aspects of the code to look like a different page with a different POST action - it also notes there is no ID passed in.

I add an item, and the POST redirects back to the same page; this time, though, there is no Id from the server, meaning the code behind picks up the fact it is a new entry, and performs an insert. It then either displays a success message with a link to view/edit the new item, or a failure message with a prepopulated form to reduce retyping the new item into the form.

I hope this has helped show how this page works; its not necessarily how I would have written the site, but I've inherited the work from an ongoing situation and work with others who code in this way, so I need to be consistent or make unobtrusive changes rather than radical redesigns of in-use code.

Comment: I suspect going back 2 pages would solve your problem, but maybe I did not get what you exactly want.

Comment: The main focus of the question is whether code can be put in the goBack() that removes/unsets POST data when navigating back via javascript's window.history.back().
The button is present on all pages; would there be a way of determining if there is POST data, and then to go back two pages if it were present? Not sure if that provides the kind of functionality required, but willing to try it if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do the job:

```
function goBack() { 
    var referrer = document.referrer;
    if(referrer != '') {
        window.location = referrer;
    } else {
        window.history.back();
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this code sets the previously viewed page as the page to go back to; navigating from "page 1" -> "page 2" -> "page 3" -> "page 4" then pressing back three times goes 4->3->4->3, rather than 4->3->2->1. Navigation through the history stack is necessary, I think; it is more to do with stripping the POST data out somehow, or  omitting the POST that is performed with the page when the back button is pressed.

Comment: Unfortunetly I do not know a way to get the url of "history.go(-1)".
I think it's not allowed for privacy reasons

Comment: By the way why do not you reload the landing page?

Comment: I'm a little confused by your terminology of "landing page", but I assume you mean the page that is got to by pressing the back button. I was under the impression that the page would be reloaded as part of the window.history.back() operation; if there is a way of making the page reload without POST data, then that would solve my problem.

Comment: I'm not sure if this will work but what I mean is to reload the page to witch you post your data.
For example: 
1. /page1.php posts data to /page2.php
2. /page2.php uses the data and reloads itself
3. you use "window.history.back();" on the reloaded /page2.php

Comment: I'll edit my question to better describe the situation navigation wise, as this suggestion won't work.